# token removal using a bash alias?

Tags: bash, alias

For example (`<magic>` being where the delete key would go):

```
$ alias test="testrunner test/test_<magic>"
$ test module.py
.....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

I've had a few cases over the years where this would be handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not off the top of my head - but if I understand your intent correctly, a bash function might be better than an alias:

```
  $ mytest(){ testrunner test/test_${1} ; }
  $ mytest module.py
```

Comment: Yeah, I can do pretty much anything with a function. One or two more things and aliases would be so much more powerful. Virtually everything I do could be fairly short one-liners in my `.bash-aliases` file.

Comment: @Gary Fixler: That's still a pretty short one-liner for your bash .profile instead. Aliases are straight text substitution, they are not interpreted any further, so even if you put a delete character in one (you can) it would not do what you want. And `man bash` says: **"For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."**

Comment: Oh well. I think I'm trying to make bash have Vim mappings. I'll just have to use it the way it's meant to be used. Thanks!